# Client-Server Architecture /State Model and Process Mode

Tags: distributed-systems

how i can define what are Client-Server Architecture for a website that suggestion courses for students after  students insert the history of courses. The language will be PHP,mysql and HTML. In this case ,server side is the PHP and client side will be the HTML . Is that how i can define the Architecture? If no , what are the process to follow to defined it ? Also,what are the State Model and Process Mode?

Comment: This is a software engineering question, not a computer science question. Furthermore it's far too broad and vague to be answerable.